# Ionic: Platform pauze/resume subscriptions

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework

Something strange is going on when `platform.resume` is triggered.

After the iPhone app comes out of pause mode, the UI no longer updates properly. I do an http get in the `platform.resume.subscription` to refresh the data. I can see that this happens almost immediately and the data is in the store. However, the UI update is extremely slow or not at all.

I’ve been able to find a semi solution, but this one doesn’t always work either and feels hacky.

```
this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => this.ngZone.run(() => {
// my http get code and ngrx store dispatch
});
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this better?

Comment: use `NgZone`. When your app resumes your UI is out of Angular Zone.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib how would you correctly implement this?

Comment: in `constructor( private zone: NgZone)` in code: `this.zone.run(() => {
        //your Code here
});`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib how is that different from my current implementation?